# MySQL stored procedure takes much longer on server than localhost

Tags: mysql, webserver, localhost

I have created a stored procedure with a query which runs on localhost:

21 rows fetched in 0,0065s (0,1426s)

And on server:

21 rows fetched in 0,0037s (15,9947s)

I have tried the following options to get the same results on localhost as server:

- SQL_NO_CACHE
- Resetting the cache
- Flushing the cache

But it doesn't give me the same results, so I'm wondering why the query running on the server is that much slower.

I have run an Explain, but don't really know what I can ready from it:

```
1, 'PRIMARY', '<derived2>', 'ALL', '', '', '', '', 16106, 100.00, 'Using temporary; Using filesort'
1, 'PRIMARY', 'A', 'ALL', 'PRIMARY', '', '', '', 5214, 100.00, 'Using where; Using join buffer'
2, 'DERIVED', 'T', 'ALL', 'PRIMARY', '', '', '', 76211, 100.00, 'Using wher
```

e'

And this is the query I'm running:

```
SELECT
        `A`.`country_description`,
    SUM(`turnover_ytd`) AS `turnover_currentyear_ytd`,
    SUM(`turnover_ly`) AS `turnover_lastyear_ytd`,
    SUM(`turnover_sly`) AS `turnover_2ndlastyear_ytd`,
    SUM(`turnover_ytd`) AS `volume_currentyear_ytd`,
    SUM(`turnover_ly`) AS `volume_lastyear_ytd`,
    SUM(`turnover_sly`) AS `volume_2ndlastyear_ytd`,
    COALESCE(((SUM(`turnover_ytd`)-SUM(`turnover_ly`))/SUM(`turnover_ly`))*100, 0) AS `turnover_percentage_currentandlastyear_ytd`,
        COALESCE(((SUM(`volume_ytd`)-SUM(`volume_ly`))/SUM(`volume_ly`))*100, 0) AS `volume_percentage_currentandlastyear_ytd`,
        COALESCE(((SUM(`turnover_ly`)-SUM(`turnover_sly`))/SUM(`turnover_sly`))*100, 0) AS `turnover_percentage_lastand2ndlastyear_ytd`,
        COALESCE(((SUM(`volume_ly`)-SUM(`volume_sly`))/SUM(`volume_sly`))*100, 0) AS `volume_percentage_lastand2ndlastyear_ytd`


  FROM
        `agent` AS `A`
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                `debtor_number`,
                IF(SUBSTR(`period`,1,4) = SUBSTR(201210,1,4), `turnover_ytd`, 0) AS `turnover_ytd`,
                IF(SUBSTR(`period`,1,4) = SUBSTR(201210-100,1,4), `turnover_ytd`, 0) AS `turnover_ly`,
        IF(SUBSTR(`period`,1,4) = SUBSTR(201210-200,1,4), `turnover_ytd`, 0) AS `turnover_sly`,
        IF(SUBSTR(`period`,1,4) = SUBSTR(201210,1,4), `volume_ytd`, 0) AS `volume_ytd`,
                IF(SUBSTR(`period`,1,4) = SUBSTR(201210-100,1,4), `volume_ytd`, 0) AS `volume_ly`,
        IF(SUBSTR(`period`,1,4) = SUBSTR(201210-200,1,4), `volume_ytd`, 0) AS `volume_sly`
            FROM
                `turnover_volume` AS `T`
            WHERE
        `company_number` = 01
      AND
        SUBSTR(`period`,5,2) <= SUBSTR(201210,5,2)
      AND
        SUBSTR(`period`,1,4) IN (SUBSTR(201210,1,4), SUBSTR(201210-100,1,4), SUBSTR(201210-200,1,4))
      AND
        `turnover_ytd` != 0
      AND
        `volume_ytd` != 0

    ) AS `T` ON (`T`.`debtor_number` = `A`.`debtor_number`)

    WHERE
    `A`.`agent_number` = 003
  GROUP BY
    `A`.`country_description`;
```

Server specs are:

The host is the physical server where ESX is running and the webserver is running virtually as a guest inside the ESX.

Host specs are:

Brand and Type: Altos R720
CPU: Xeon E5404 (2ghz)
Storage: Connected via storage via Iscsi. (Eternus DX80)
Memory: 6 GB

Guest specs are:
CPU: 2x vCPU
Memory: 2 GB

OS is: Red Hat 4.1.2-44

Apart from these specs, the guest has unlimited access to the host.

My local PC specs are:

CPU: Intel Core 2 Quad CPU Q9300 @ 2.50GHz
Memory: 3 GB
OS: Windows 7 32-bit

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem, somehow the Collation types where different on the webserver compared to my localhost database.

On localhost I have:

latin1_swedish_ci

and on the server it was:

utf8_unicode_ci

Also the engine on the tables were different, InnoDB vs MyIsam on server...

This caused to slow the queries alot by going over the translations between the different Collation types.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the hardware of the server compared to your local machine?

Is this a shared hosting package? Dedicated server? Cloud?

Comment: It is a Linux server, running locally at our office:

Linux version 2.6.18-128.1.1.el5 (mockbuild@hs20-bc1-5.build.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)) #1 SMP Mon Jan 26 13:59:00 EST 2009

With MySQL:

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.50, for redhat-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 5.1

Comment: Can you update your question with Ram,CPU, OS and if it's shared or dedicated for both the local and live server?

Comment: I have updated my question with the specifications, could you take another look at this question please?